# How to solve a numerical reasoning grid pattern with numbers and letters.

Tags: logic

I'm having trouble solving a question in which there is a 6x6 grid pattern. One of the rows have been erased and I need to find what number or letter is in the grid square with the question mark.

- 2 A 4 A 6 A
- C B 4 B 6 B
- 4 4 4 C 6 C
- ```
    ?
  ```
- 6 6 6 6 6 E
- K J I H G F

The answer is e, yet I cannot find why that would be the answer. Please help.

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HluJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is off-topic here.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  Where should i post the question then, if it being here is off-topic?

Comment: You could try [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), but I doubt that it's on-topic there.

Comment: I think the answer is "E" (option D in the picture).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you still need the answer, but I've found the pattern. It's a reverse $L$, starting from the top right corner, going down, then to the left. If the column $n$ starts with a number, you repeat that number in the entire pattern: go down $n-1$ rows, then go left $n-1$ columns. Similar pattern fro the letters, but you fill with $A,B,C,D, ...$. To check the result, the erased row would be $GFED6D$. Then the question mark is letter $E$, option $D$ in the question.